# Harvest JS generated Image URI using SeleniumJS

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, base64, png

I have been trying to write a python script to allow me to harvest QR codes from whatsapp web. I use selenium but can't seem to get it to write.

The QR image is a PNG generated by a javascript live (hence selenium) in which it is converted to a PNG in Base64 and translated by the browser to an image.

The code I've got to so far does this:

```
import base64
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://web.whatsapp.com"
init_search = "<img style=\"display: block;\" src=\"data:image/png;base64,"
term_search = "\"></div>"

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
html_source = browser.page_source

start = html_source.find(init_search)
end = html_source[start:].find(term_search)

raw_png = html_source[start+len(init_search):end]

print html_source[start:end]
print base64.b64decode(raw_png)

browser.close()
```

But it's not really stable. How to do this, and if possible without actually opening the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for not opening the browser, you can try a headless web browser like Phantom.js, which will work in your terminal.

http://phantomjs.org/